# React: Map over Array of Obects (fake data) to render an Array of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I'm able to display the content from spellingListData object. It is displaying all the words in one h1 tag. That is not what I'm needing right now.

If I turn spellingListData into one Array with all the words, then I'm able to map and create multiple h1 tags for each item in the array. That is what I"m wanting - assign each word with an h1 tag.

What am I missing? I've been stuck on this one. How do I drill down into the object's array? I've tried word[0].spellingwords which didn't work?

Data Component:

```
    import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import WordList from "./WordList";
 
function Data(props) {
  const [words, setWords] = useState(spellingListData);
  return (
    <div>
      <WordList words={words} />
    </div>
  );
}
// Simulated Data
const spellingListData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    spellingWords: ["careful", "stared", "shared", "pair", "stairs", "wear", "bear", "where", "there", "dear", "rear", "gear", "here", "career", "peer", "shore", "carve", "storm"],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bonusWords: ["January", "parable"],
  },
];
 
export default Data;
```

WordList Component:

```
      import React from "react";
 
function WordList({ words }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        words.map((word) => {
          return <h1 key={word.id}>{word.spellingWords}</h1>;
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default WordList;
```

Comment: you need to map again through the array of spellingWords. In the arrow function which is inside map you have to map twice to get inside the array. so use return(word.spellingWords.map((eachWord) => (<h1 key={word.id}>{eachWord}</h1>))) this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map on the *spellingWords* array:

```
function WordList({ words }) {
 return (
   <div>
     {
       words[0].spellingWords.map( word =>
          (<h1 key={word}>{word}</h1>)
        )
     }
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @KaranSingh. Now, I see exactly what was wrong.